# Linux to Windows SSH authorized_keys

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I want to connect into a Windows Box from my Ubuntu PC via ssh using key authentication but I don't know how to do it.

I've tried to send the `id_rsa.pub` to Windows and then rename it to `authorized_keys` (placing this file into the `C:\Users\Administrador\.ssh\`'s directory), but it keeps prompting me the password. It seems like the system doesn't recognize the file properly.

I've also tried with `ssh-copy-id`'s command but after connecting to Windows it gives me an error.

Any solution?

PS: I am using OpenSSH for Windows installed through the Chocolatey repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have luck with `ssh-copy-id` under windows so send the contents of your public key on a different way like copy and paste while connected via ssh by password.

Than you can try different locations for the `authorized_keys` file.

1. Your users `.ssh` folder
2. Your users `.ssh` folder, but call the file `administrators_authorized_keys`. This is needed if your user has admin rights.
3. In the folder `C:\ProgramData\ssh`
4. In the folder `C:\ProgramData\ssh`, but call the file `administrators_authorized_keys`. This is needed if your user has admin rights.

For me, solution 4 worked. I installed openSSH server by activating a windows 11 feature, not via choco.